# Show that $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^{s}}$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, mobius-function

> Show that $$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^{s}}.$$

I'm trying to show the above and we haven't covered Euler's product formula yet so I don't think we can use that in our proof. I think that maybe we could use Dirichlet convolution in some way but that's defined for sums over the divisors of n, which the above are not so I'm stuck. Any hints on the way to proceed without Euler's product formula would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Write $1=\zeta(s)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$.  Maybe you can use this property of the Mobius function: $\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)=0$ for all integers $n>1$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool How can we apply that property when the sum isn't over the divisors of $n$?

Comment: Multiply through your equation by $\zeta(s)$, replace $\zeta$ by its Dirichlet series and perform the product of the two Dirichlet series. The result is a single Dirichlet series. What are the coefficients of this series?

Comment: @Gary Ok I think I get what you're saying but I think I made a mistake. So we had $\zeta(s)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(n)/n^{s} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1 * \mu(n)}{n^{s}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sum_{d\mid n} \mu(d)}{n^{s}} = \zeta(s)$.

Comment: $\zeta(s)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(n)/n^{s} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1 * \mu(n)}{n^{s}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sum_{d\mid n} \mu(d)}{n^{s}} =1+ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{0}{n^{s}}=1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more general answer.  Let $\Bbb N$ here denote the set of positive integers, and suppose that $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb C$ is an arithmetic function such that $f(1)\neq 0$.  Define
$$F(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{f(n)}{n^s}$$
where $s\in S$ and $S\subseteq\Bbb C$ is the set of values $s$ s.t. $F(s)$ absolutely converges.

Then for all $s\in S$,
$$\frac{1}{F(s)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\hat{f}(n)}{n^s},$$
where $\hat{f}$ is the [Dirichlet inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution#Dirichlet_inverse) of $f$.  That is, $\hat{f}:\Bbb N\to\Bbb C$ is the unique arithmetic function s.t.
$$\hat{f}*f=\epsilon=f*\hat{f},$$
where $*$ is the Dirichlet convolution and $\epsilon$ is the identity function for the Dirichlet convolution.  This is because
$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{f(n)}{n^s}\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\hat{f}(n)}{n^s}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(f*\hat{f})(n)}{n^s}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\epsilon(n)}{n^s}=1.$$

In the OP's problem where $F=\zeta$, $f$ is the constant function $\texttt{1}$.  Since $\mu*\texttt{1}=\epsilon$, $\mu=\hat{\texttt{1}}$.  The claim follows.